# Permission denied error using DOM in UFT

Tags: javascript, qtp

I am writing an automation script in UFT
Workflow is as below?:
There is a frame which has a dropdown list.I Select an option from the dropdown list, perform an action using it.This action opens a new page.Now on the new page I can edit .On editing, the same frame opens in edit mode withe the preselection in the drop down list.Now I want to select the next option from the list and perform the same action.However UFT throws an error "permission denied" on the statement where I am performing the selection(Set OptionsList=SelectTag1.options).Code is as below:

Set SelectTag1=objFrame.Object.GetElementById("xyz")

```
    Set OptionsList=SelectTag1.options
    For i=0 to OptionsList.length-1
        OptionDisabled=OptionsList(i).disabled

       If (OptionDisabled="False") Then
            OptionValue=OptionsList(i).value
            SelectTag1.value=OptionValue
            Call AddCriteria()
            Call Edit()
       end if
    next
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read this essay on [how QTP identifies objects](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/The-Future-of-Testing-Blog/Technical-How-QTP-identifies-Objects/ba-p/2409612).

I think the problem you're facing may be caused by the *runtime id* being invalidated and that you need to be using the `RefreshObject` function.

Comment: Did that ,however didn't solve the problem
 Set OptionsList2=SelectTag2.options
This doesn't get created